# Chrome resizing makes children elements too large on certain zoom levels

Tags: css, google-chrome

When you zoom in Google Chrome, some zoom levels cause the children elements to be larger than the parent element. Is there a way to fix this?

If you look at my example, I would like two children elements per row. This means the two children elements will fill the entire width of the parent element when combining their widths and margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/4tpLjL7u/

CSS

```
.parent {
  background: black;
  height: 404px;
  width: 404px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: blue;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one"></div>
  <div class="child two"></div>
  <div class="child two second"></div>
  <div class="child one second"></div>
</div>
```

However, when zooming out it sometimes only has enough room to allow one child element per row.

I do not observe this issue in IE / Edge.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like there's a known bug in Chrome which causes behaviour like this. Zooming in and out can cause small visual glitches. I've looked around for a fix for you but haven't found something definitive. Here is one way to change your code to get the result you want:

Set the font-size of the parent element to 0.

```
.parent {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

This will remove the borders between the child divs. When you zoom now all the divs will render correctly, however you no longer have borders separating the child divs...

To fix this you can use pseudo-elements before and after the parent div, which will be positioned where the border was.

```
.parent {
  position: relative; /* add this */
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  height: 4px;
  width: 404px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.parent:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  height: 404px;
  width: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

You can see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/cfuhcsrt/

I realise this is a lot to fix such a small glitch, and may be impractical depending on your needs, hopefully there is a better solution.

Comment: thanks, I will give this a try and remember for future